# How to properly popup and resize Dialog from another .qml file

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

Learning qml and trying to separate main window and settings in different files. I have a SettingsView.qml with simple Dialog and Have a main.qml where I call menu and call my settings dialog to popup. When I had a Dialog in main.qml it was fine and it had been resizing with whole window properly. But after I had moved it to different file the behaviour changed. Now also I recieve a message: *"refSettingsDialog is not defined"*. I would be gratefull for any advices.

upd: Closed. No need in properties here etc just basics. And do not call id from another file. Atleast, as I understand it by now

SettingsView.qml

```
Dialog{
    id: settingsDialog
    modal: true
    focus: true
    title: "Settings"

    standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel
    onAccepted: {
        settingsDialog.close()
    }
    onRejected: {
        settingsDialog.close()
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    id: screen
    property alias mainScreen: screen
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property alias screenWidth: screen.width
    property alias screenHeight: screen.height
    title: qsTr("McdtViewer")
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    Material.accent: Material.Yellow

    SystemPalette { id: activePalette  }

    //toolbar
    header: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            spacing: 20
            anchors.fill: parent

            ToolButton {
                icon.name: contentSwiper.currentIndex === 1 ? "Back" : "пустой"
                onClicked:  {
                    if (contentSwiper.currentIndex === 1){
                        contentSwiper.pop()
                    }
                }
            }

            Label {
                id: titleLabel
                text: contentSwiper.currentIndex === 0? "ExpWatcher": "ExpView"
                font.pixelSize: 20
                elide: Label.ElideRight
                horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
            ToolButton {
                icon.name: "menu"
                onClicked: optionsMenu.open()

                Menu {
                    id: optionsMenu
                    x: parent.width - width
                    transformOrigin: Menu.TopRight

                    MenuItem {
                        text: "Settings"
                        //calling the instance of settingView which we declared in the bottom
                        onTriggered: {
                             settingsView.open()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
    // making instance of settingsDialog here so the width will be calculated properly.
    SettingsView{
        id: settingsView
        x: Math.round((screenWidth - width) / 2)
        y: Math.round(screenHeight / 6)
        width: Math.round(Math.min(screenWidth, screenHeight) / 3 * 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: `ApplicationWindow` inside `Dialog`? For what?

Comment: I wanted an instance of application’s window to get its size. It’s one of iterations of my tries to achieve what I want.

Comment: Ok, what you are doing here is just creating another instance on `ApplicationWindow` (with zero size btw) which sounds at least weird. You should access existing one by `id`.

Comment: ok, thx. So I reworked a bit to simplify it and came to earlier state with link error  "refSettingsDialog is not defined"

Comment: Ok, I made it. It was all about my lack of understanding of principles wich qml are based on. I updated the code in question.